# How do I loop through table elements AND retrieve data elements using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table that looks like this in a standard HTML 4.01 Transitional page:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>etc...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBodyID">
    <tr class="rowElement" data-element="some-data-here">
      <td>Some Table Data</td>
      <td>Some More Table data</td>
      <td>etc.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowElement" data-element="some-data-here">
      <td>Some Table Data</td>
      <td>Some More Table data</td>
      <td>etc.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to loop through all the rows and get the "data" in the data-element field and place it in a variable using JQuery.  I have tried a number of variations of .children(), .data(), and .each() but have not been able to retrieve the "data" elements.

I have tried (inside a $(document).ready() block...):

```
$('tbody > tr').each(function() {
  alert( $(this).data('element'));  // CORRECTION - this works.
});

$('tbody').children().each(function() {
  alert( $(this).data('element'));  // CORRECTION - this works
});

$('.rowElement').each(function(i, obj) {
  rowValue = $(this);
  alert(rowValue.data('element'));  // CORRECTION - this works
});
```

Any help is welcome. I am using HTML 4.01, and JQuery 1.7.1.  I have been testing in Firefox, but need to support the other standard browser Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome, and IE8+.

(Edited for minor syntax changes)

The actual problem was a case issue, please see comment below.  Issue RESOLVED.

Comment: I discovered my answer, was using the wrong case in my data-element.  In my html it was data-Element, and I don't know if it is the browser, javascript, or jquery but data-Element was turned into data-element, so that when I called the var as I named it .data('Element') there was do data element by that name.  Thanks for all the input, and I like the code that I've seen.  But in this case it was a simple case error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$('table').find('tbody > tr').each(function() {
  alert( $(this).data('element')); 
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/LBKvm/

(it may not be the most efficient way however)

Answer (score 1):

Using `.map` and `.get`, you can map each `tr` into the `element` data attribute, so as to get an array of those values. As for the selector, an ID is the most straight-forward since it points directly to the `tbody` element, of which you want the `tr` descendants: http://jsfiddle.net/zeFGW/.

```
var elementValues = $("#tableBodyID tr.rowElement").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("element"); // replace each `tr` with its `element` data
}).get(); // turn jQuery object into an array
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for however it does a wonderful job and I may end up changing the way I process the data to use this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic/calls work for me, you have a few issues with syntax though, brackets after `('element');`'s should be `('element'));` and the selectors need to be quoted also, the tbody ones are missing should be `('tbody')` etc.

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbsED/). (Note my replacement of alert to console.log calls)

Tested in chrome 17.

Is your code different from what is posted in the question?

Comment: If you're still having issues let me know i'll update my answer as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the help I found the solution, my html is remarkably more complex as it is dynamically generated from several places, I was putting up a sample that tried to only show the parts relevant to the problem (or the perceived problem).  The problem ended up being a case issue in the data-element name.  When I generated the mark up i was using a capital in the name, and I don't know if it is the programing language I'm using, or the browser, javascript, or jquery,... but it only worked when I used all lower case in the name.

Comment: good stuff, glad you got it fixed, my go to guess for what it was would be jquery